# How to hide the “About Me” link from the username drop down list

Tags: master-page, page-layout, css

We have built our team site, for adding Apps and different contents, but for now we do not want to have About me page for each user. So is there a way to remove the “About me” link from the username drop down list. I do not want to remove the About Me site itself as we might need it later. But I need to hide the About me link as shown below:-

[image]

::EDIT::
I tried adding the following custom CSS:-

```
#ID_AboutMe
{ 
display: none;
}
```

It will hide the option text, but still the user can click on its empty area as shown below:-

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use Css in this case. Use JQuery instead because you have inheritance of styles and you can hide other things.

put the following code in a script javascript tag

```
$("#ID_AboutMe").closest("li").hide();
```

I assume that you have jquery library referenced

Comment: i added your code at the seatle.master page inside a script tag, but it did not hide the "About Me" link . and the SharePoint designer display an underline below the $ at the begining of my code

Comment: Are you using JQuery references in your master page?

Comment: it worked well.

Answer (score 3):

I found this solution from http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0cfdd44a-492d-4382-9981-2004d751cb01/how-to-hide-the-about-me-link-from-the-username-drop-down-list?forum=sharepointdevelopment

Many thanks to Geetanjali who posted the solution.

I added the script:

```
<style type="text/css">
.ms-core-menu-list li[text='About Me'] { display: none;}
</style>
```

to my custom master page using SharePoint Designer 2013 and it works for the sites I have been working on.

The About Me Link has been hidden.

Answer (score 1):

If you go the JavaScript way, this may guarantee that your item gets removed, even on slower connected browsers.  I would run the following within a $(window).load() event...

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $("#ID_AboutMe").remove();
}, 1000);
```

Just my 2cents