# Hiding 'About Me' from users from the Username drop down list

Tags: javascript, jquery, branding

I'm using 2013 Enterprise and have customized a copy of seattle.master. I'm editing the seattle_custom.html and uploading the changes and publishing a major version. So far I've not been able to get this bugger to disappear! Here's what I've tried:

I've added `.ms-core-menu-list li[text='About Me'] {display: none;}` as the last item before the closing head tag.

I've added `$("#ID_AboutMe").closest("li").hide();` to the bottom of the page in a `document.ready` function.

Answer (score 1):

That should work (it did through debugger for me). Have you tried putting it into the CSS attached to the master page (where these should be anyway)?

Alternatively, you can try appending !important to the CSS code, which can bump it up in priority over any out of the box CSS code.

ex:

```
.ms-core-menu-list li[text='About Me'] 
{display: none !important;}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I added the !important attribute and published a new major version but it still shows up.  I noticed that there is a function that is showing up on the page called ctl00_ctl19_SocialNavControl_insertMyProfileMenu() which gets injected at the very bottom of the page which sets the anchor elements and pushes it to the page. with _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push('ctl00_ctl19_SocialNavControl_insertMyProfileMenu') So I need to find a means, I believe, to inject my change after that loads.

Comment: What worked, for IE and FireFox but not Chrome, is: document.getElementById('ID_AboutMe').style.visibility = 'hidden';

Comment: Here's a Stack Exchange article that has some more info: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/77387/how-to-hide-the-about-me-link-from-the-username-drop-down-list

It basically pushes you towards jQuery (a good idea if you want to do things after load especially) 

$("#ID_AboutMe").closest("li").hide();